# In Unity, while debugging, If I watch "System.Text.RegularExpressions.GroupCollection".Item[String], it gives an error

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Regular Expression in Unity.(Unity2020.3 with Visual2019)

As shown in the picutre below.
I can use groups[str] to get the group.
But while debugging, watching it will raise an error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just looked into this and I first though: well this may be the result of some side effect that the debugger tries to avoid. However in other cases the debugger happily evaluates expressions with side effects.

So I checked the relevant code and found something strange. This is the implementation of the two indexers:

```
public Group this[int groupnum] => GetGroup(groupnum);
public Group this[string groupname]
{
    get
    {
        if (_match._regex == null)
        {
            return Group._emptygroup;
        }
        return GetGroup(_match._regex.GroupNumberFromName(groupname));
    }
}
```

Since the evaluation leads to "one or more errors occurred" I thought the issue must be either in the `GetGroup` method, or in the `GroupNumberFromName` method. Nowever evaluating `groups[1]` does return the group just fine.

So it has to be GroupNumberFromName, right?

Well, I also evaluated `rx.GroupNumberFromName("TheGroup")` and it returns `1` as it should without any issues.

So I evaluated `groups[rx.GroupNumberFromName("TheGroup")]` and it also works. This is almost literally the same thing that the string parameter indexer itself does internally. However for some reason the debugger has issues evaluating the expression.

So I would assume some strange behaviour / bug in the debugger / code analyser which causes this behaviour. Maybe someone who actually works on the debugger could shed some light here, though I don't think we get much more information on that issue. It seems to be a mysterious limitation of the debugger. A bug report wouldn't hurt I guess.

Personally I always try to avoid too complex expressions in the watch window, especially those which could have side effects.

Comment: Thank you. Where do you find the "the relevant code" ?

Comment: I don't quite know how the c# in unity is implemented. Is it Mono or IL2CPP? And then is "the relevant code" from Mono or IL2CPP?

Comment: "Personally I always try to avoid too complex expressions in the watch window, especially those which could have side effects.", I don't have this congnition, it helps, thanks for your share. By the way, I think groups["TheGroup"] has no side effects, am I right?

Comment: GetGroup actually does have side effects (it creates the internal _groups array and the groups on first access). Though that shouldn't matter. The Regex class is part of the .NET / Mono framework. You can find it with ILSpy or any other .NET reflector. The Regex class is usually defined inside the System.dll assembly. [Here's the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexGroupCollection.cs,97).

Comment: Here's the reference source for the [GroupNumberFromName method](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/Regex.cs,673) inside the Regex class. It essentially just looks up the name in the internal "capnames" hashtable.As I said, both parts work individually and when put manually in a watch it also works.

Comment: Thank you again. Your answer is helpful. I still do not quite understand .NET,Mono,IL2CPP these stuff. But as time passes by, I think I will.